# Tokenizing a complex string (a Snort rule) with regular expressions (.NET)

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need help from the Regex wizards out there.  I am trying to write a simple parser that can tokenize the options list of a Snort rule (Snort, the IDS/IPS software).  Problem is, I can't seem to find a workable formula that breaks apart the individual rule options based on their terminating semi-colon.  The formulas that I have cooked up grab all options between parenthesis into a single capture group.

I am using the excellent [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) tool at the GSkinner site with some of the below sample rule options from Emerging Threats (I parsed off the rule header -- that's easy to tokenize):

```
(msg:"ET DELETED Majestic-12 Spider Bot User-Agent (MJ12bot)"; flow:to_server,established; content:"|0d 0a|User-Agent\: MJ12bot|0d 0a|"; classtype:trojan-activity; reference:url,www.majestic12.co.uk/; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2003409; reference:url,www.emergingthreats.net/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/sigs/POLICY/POLICY_Majestic-12; sid:2003409; rev:4;)
(msg:"ET DELETED Majestic-12 Spider Bot User-Agent Inbound (MJ12bot)"; flow:to_server,established; content:"|0d 0a|User-Agent\: MJ12bot"; classtype:trojan-activity; reference:url,www.majestic12.co.uk/; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2007762; reference:url,www.emergingthreats.net/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/sigs/POLICY/POLICY_Majestic-12; sid:2007762; rev:4;)
(msg:"ET POLICY McAfee Update User Agent (McAfee AutoUpdate)"; flow:to_server,established; content:"User-Agent|3a| "; http_header; nocase; content:"McAfee AutoUpdate"; http_header; pcre:"/User-Agent\x3a[^\n]+McAfee AutoUpdate/i"; classtype:not-suspicious; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2003381; reference:url,www.emergingthreats.net/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/sigs/POLICY/POLICY_McAffee; sid:2003381; rev:6;)
(msg:"ET DELETED Metacafe.com family filter off"; flow:established,to_server; content:"POST"; http_method; content:"Host|3a| www.metacafe.com"; http_header; fast_pattern:6,16; content:"submit=Continue+-+I%27m+over+18"; classtype:policy-violation; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2006367; reference:url,www.emergingthreats.net/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/sigs/POLICY/POLICY_Metacafe; sid:2006367; rev:7;)
```

And this is the formula:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_:]+(?:[\w\s.,\-/=<>+!\[\]\(\)\{\}\"|\\;'?`~@#$%^&*])+;)
```

The problem is, it doesn't handle colons.  So two of the rules above will not have their 'content' options properly parsed.  But on RegExr, each option will be highlighted in blue, including the terminating semi-colon, but NOT the space after the semi-colon.  If I fed this into .NET, I should be able to do a Regex.Split and break apart all the tokens correctly.

If I add the colon to the character list, then on RegExr, the entire set of rules will get tokenized as a single blob of text, which is not what I want.  Further attempts to tweak the formula result in Adobe Flash crashing, indicating I'm hitting a bug in either Flash or RegExr.

I've not ruled out writing my own string tokenizer, but I was hoping regex could save me from dealing with things like counting my open quotations, escaped characters, whitespace, etc.

Snort rule options typically come in the following format:

```
option:value;
option:"string value";
option:!"negated string value";
option:>num;
option:param1,param2,param3;
```

But several options tend to have more 'exotic' formats for their value, like byte_test.  And everyone's favourite, 'pcre', which is basically an option for performing perl-compatible regex's.  So any such tokenizer has to avoid getting confused if it runs into the 'pcre' keyword with regex in it.

Thoughts?
**Edit:**
This below is REALLY close:

```
([\w]+:?(?:[\x20]|)?(?:[\x00-\xff])*?;)
```

But, according to RegExr, it gets messed by pcre syntax:

```
(msg:"ET WEB_SPECIFIC_APPS Horde 3.0.9-3.1.0 Help Viewer Remote PHP Exploit"; flow:established,to_server; content:"/services/help/"; nocase; http_uri; pcre:"/module=[^\;]*\;.*\"/UGi"; classtype:web-application-attack; reference:url,www.milw0rm.com/exploits/1660; reference:cve,2006-1491; reference:bugtraq,17292; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2002867; reference:url,www.emergingthreats.net/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/sigs/WEB_SPECIFIC_APPS/WEB_Horde; sid:2002867; rev:9; http_method;)
```

In the above, every single option is highlighted as a distinct grouping, except **`]*\;.*\"/`**.  I would think that `\x00-\xff` would get it all, but it appears that I am using a lazy match.  A greedy match gets everything, including all the spaces between options, which I do not want.  So I need to somehow modify the regex to handle tokenizing pcre text.
**Edit2:**This does the trick:

```
([\w]+:?(?:[\x20]|)?(?<!\\)\"?.*?(?<!\\)\"?;)
```

I had to play with a few example regex's that work with quoted strings.  Finally realized that I am staring at negative look-behinds that avoid quotes that are escaped.  This seems to solve any other escaped character, too, because escaped characters only appear inside unescaped quotes.

Comment: Snort's an intrusion detection system, so it's basically like grep for network traffic.  One of its rule options is literally named "pcre", Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions.  It looks like this: `pcre:"/[a-z0-9]/i";` in the rule chain.  It links into libpcre to handle any needed regex parsing.

Comment: As for how I want it tokenized, I want to grab anything inside the opening/closing parenthesis, split on the semi-colons terminating each option, and stick those into an array.  I cannot use the standard .NET string split functions, because options like 'content' or 'pcre' can have a semi-colon inside of them, which would throw off the splitter and output things incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for lookaround. Just carefully write the regex to precisely match what you need. This is made much clearer (and easier to maintain) by writing this in verbose free-spacing mode like so: (Although VB.NET syntax makes it awkward to do so)

```vb
Dim RegexObj As New Regex(
    "# Match set of Snort rules enclosed within parentheses." & chr(10) & _
    "\(                              # Literal opening parentheses." & chr(10) & _
    "(?:                             # Group for one or more rules." & chr(10) & _
    "  \w+                           # Required rule name." & chr(10) & _
    "  (?:                           # Group for optional rule value." & chr(10) & _
    "    :                           # Rule name/values separated by :" & chr(10) & _
    "    (?:                         # Group for rule value alternatives." & chr(10) & _
    "      ""                        # Either a double quoted string," & chr(10) & _
    "      [^""\\]*                  # {normal} Use ""Unrolling the Loop""." & chr(10) & _
    "      (?:                       # Begin {(special normal*)*} construct." & chr(10) & _
    "        \\.                     # {special} == escaped anything." & chr(10) & _
    "        [^""\\]*                # More {normal*} non-quote, non-escapes." & chr(10) & _
    "      )*                        # Finish {(special normal*)*} construct." & chr(10) & _
    "      ""                        # Closing quote." & chr(10) & _
    "    | '[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'  # or a single quoted string," & chr(10) & _
    "    | [^;]+                     # or one or more non semi-colons." & chr(10) & _
    "    )                           # End group for rule value options." & chr(10) & _
    "  )?                            # Rule value is optional." & chr(10) & _
    "  ; \s*                         # Rule ends with ;, optional ws." & chr(10) & _
    ")+                              # One or more rules." & chr(10) & _
    "\)                              # LiteraL closing parentheses.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
Dim MatchResults As Match = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString)
While MatchResults.Success
    ' matched text: MatchResults.Value
    ' match start: MatchResults.Index
    ' match length: MatchResults.Length
    MatchResults = MatchResults.NextMatch()
End While
```

This regex demonstrates use of Jeffrey Friedl's *"Unrolling the Loop"* efficiency technique for correctly matching quoted strings which may contain escaped characters. (See:  [MRE3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124))

Oh yeah, one more thing... *Icarus has found you!*

Comment: I'll give you the answer because the other guy deleted his and I guess didn't want to try and fix it.  I dropped regex anyways -- it was far too time-consuming when iterated multiple times.  I instead wrote a simple parser that only looks for backslash-escaped double-quotes and backslashes so that I would track where I am inside a quoted string.  I don't need to actually parse the string, just know when I am inside quotes and when I am outside of the quotes so that when I hit a semi-colon, I know that I am truly at the end of the rule option.

Comment: Take that knowledge of when I hit the end of an option, and use substring to copy it to a List(Of String), and then I can chop a long rule up really fast.  Basically, using Regex and iterating 10,000 times (I think), I was in the range of 9,000ms.  Using the simple parser, I was able to bring that down to ~780ms.

Comment: And Icarus has found me?  Looks like a Deus Ex reference.  Been years since I played that game.